# IBM MQ, .NET 2/3.5 apps running on Windows using container and Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift

We have IBM MQ ver 7, and .NET 2/3.5 apps running on Windows. Is it possible to host Windows container on Openshift, or similar open source cloud platform?

Comment: It's possible to run a Windows 2016 VM that can run Windows containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows containers on openshift? **Not avialable now.**

Currently **openshift supports only linux containers and windows containers will be supported from mid of 2018**.

Refer here:

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2017/08/22/red-hat-openshift-windows-containers.aspx

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/supporting-windows-server-containers-red-hat-openshift

> Amazon:

Supported with ECS - Elastic container service. It **supports Windows containers on container instances that are launched with the Amazon ECS-optimized Windows AMI.**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_Windows.html

> Google cloud

**Supported for windows containers with below combination of resources:**

```
Includes: Docker
Image project: windows-cloud
Image family: windows-1709-core-for-containers
```

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/

> Microsoft Azure:

Supported for windows containers as well.

https://blog.vizuri.com/docker-windows-azure

https://blog.vizuri.com/docker-for-windows-vs.-docker-on-windows-server